# Append using JSON_MODIFY into a blank column fails with "Unexpected character '.' is found at position 0" error

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table with a `NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL` column with a default of empty string. The check constraint checks if the content is valid JSON if it is not null or an empty string:

```
CHECK ((ISNULL(ISJSON(NULLIF([MyJSONColumn],'')), (1)) = (1)
```

If the column already contains some JSON, for example, the following:

```
["This is some original stuff"]
```

then I can append to it using `JSON_MODIFY`.

For example, this works:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.MyJSONColumn = JSON_MODIFY(t.MyJSONColumn, 'append $', '"This is some appended stuff."')
FROM dbo.MyTable t
WHERE t.PrimaryKey = 1
```

and if I then select from the table:

```
SELECT MyJsonColumn 
FROM dbo.MyTable 
WHERE PrimaryKey = 1
```

I get my appended JSON, like so:

```
["This is some original stuff","This is some appended stuff."]
```

All is well. However, if I attempt the exact same `JSON_MODIFY` update when the column is an empty string, I get this error:

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '.' is found at position 0.

The only way I can initially set the value of a blank `MyJSONColumn` is to do something like this. This works, but is of course very ugly:

```
UPDATE t
SET t.MyJSONColumn = '["This is some stuff."]')
```

After I get that initial value in the column, I can then use `JSON_MODIFY` to append to it.

Can I use `JSON_MODIFY` to set that initial value? I've tried adding the "lax" modifier, but I still get the error (ie 'append lax $').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to change your column's default, as empty string is not a valid JSON. As such, when you pass it as the first parameter into the `JSON_MODIFY()` function, it predictably disagrees.

Depending on your needs, it might be a root array:

```sql
declare @s nvarchar(max) = '[]';
set @s = JSON_MODIFY(@s, 'append $', N'This is some appended stuff.');
select @s;
```

or a more elaborated (but extensible) structure:

```sql
declare @s nvarchar(max) = '{ "Values" : [] }';
set @s = JSON_MODIFY(@s, 'append $.Values', N'This is some appended stuff.');
select @s;
```

P.S. Your double quotes that you pass as a part of your value become escaped; if you don't need that, remove them from the incoming value, as in my examples.

Answer (score 1):

**The problem is that your constraint is wrong.**

`''` empty string **is simply *not* valid JSON**, but the constraint allows it, because of the `NULLIF`. The constraint should be

```sql
CHECK (ISJSON([MyJSONColumn]) = (1))
```

and then `''` will not be allowed.

The only issue you can have is that `JSON_MODIFY` `append` will not work on a null value. Instead, you can use a default value of `[]` which is perfectly valid JSON as an empty array.

Note that `ISNULL` is also not necessary, because a `CHECK` constraint will pass a `NULL` return from the check, as mentioned [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-of-check-constraints).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8721dba45e0c08060345801e388f524a)

Comment: After negotiations with the person who created the table, we settled on making the column nullable, with no default constraint, changing the check constraint to (ISNULL(ISJSON([MyJSONColumn]),(1))=(1)), and substituting '[]' for null values in the update statement, eg SET MyJSONColumn = JSON_MODIFY(ISNULL(MyJSONColumn,'[]'), 'append $', 'This is some stuff to append'). For reasons beyond the scope of this question the table creator could not have the column default to be empty brackets.

Comment: As I said `ISNULL` is not necessary in check constraints, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-of-check-constraints

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, you are correct, I altered by check constraint to (ISJSON([MyJSONColumn]) > 0)